# How can I upload pictures with ajax/jQuery and PHP without refreshing the page?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I am trying to allow users to upload pictures and display them on the same page. For instance Facebook allows users to choose a file and upload it when signing up without having to reload the page. How ca I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/demos/)

As @Groovetrain pointed this is flash based and you might want to consider something using iframe instead. But if flash is no problem, here is code to show the image upon uploading:

**Markup**

```
<input type="file" id="file_upload" name="file_upload" />
<a href="javascript:$('#file_upload').uploadifyUpload();">Upload Files</a>
<div id="preview"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#file_upload').uploadify({
  'uploader'    : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
  'script'      : '/uploadify/uploadify.php',
  'cancelImg'   : '/uploadify/cancel.png',
  'folder'      : '/uploads',
  'fileExt'     : '*.jpg;*.gif;*.png',
  'fileDesc'    : 'Image Files'
  'onComplete'  : function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {
      $('#preview').append('<img src="uploads/' + fileObj.name + "/>');
    }
});
```

Comment: True, but this really isn't AJAX, per sé, as it's flash-based.

Comment: Of course `onComplete` callback hook is provided by flash-less plugins as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use $post or $ajax function to get image from a file and update the div containing image.

```
$.post('file_of_image', function(data) {
  $('#image_containing_div').html(data);
});
```

In image containing file, write echo ""  and other necessary parameter in php quotes.

Answer (score 0):

One option that I have used in the past is [Ajax Upload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) by Andrew Valums.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need something without flash. To get it to work with javascript, you need a solution with iframes. (due to javascript access restrictions)
This is one nice solution with jquery: http://valums.com/ajax-upload/
You can find some more if you google something like "jquery iframe file upload"